# Required and optional parameters for Sinatra route

Tags: ruby, regex, routes, sinatra

With Sinatra routes, how can there be both a required named parameter and an optional named parameter in the same part of the route.

Optional route parameter works fine here

```
get '/widgets.?:format?'
```

But, try to combine a required named paramter, and things break.

```
get '/widgets/:id.?:format?'
```

Requests for /widgets/abc.json pass the entire abc.json as the id parameter.

The Sinatra compiled regex is:

```
/^\/widgets\/([^\/?#]+)(?:\.|%2E)?([^\/?#]+)?$/
```

Comment: This is because the regexp for matching `:id` is greedy, but adding `?` to the rest makes them ungreedy. Please open [an issue](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/new), I might be able to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did get past this by going full regex on the route and excluding the "." from the first regex group.

```
get %r{/widgets\/([^\/?#\.]+)(?:\.|%2E)?([^\/?#]+)?}
```

Comment: Did you also open an issue as @Konstantin requested?  I've run into this sort of problem before (though not actually in Sinatra) and it would be good to know it's been fixed in Sinatra.